# Save the transient instance before flushing or set cascade action for the property to something that would make it autosave

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am facing some error while it commits translation.The error is given below

> Object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing or set cascade action for the property to something that would make it autosave.

I have created a .hbm.xml file for TBASubType

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping namespace="M3.Entities" assembly="M3.Entities" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="TBASubType" table="tBASubType" schema="dbo">
    <id name="FSubTypeID" type="Guid">
      <generator class="assigned" />
    </id> <version name="FTimestamp" generated="always" unsaved-value="null" type="BinaryBlob">   <column name="FTimestamp" not-null="true" sql-type="timestamp"/>    </version>
    <property name="FType" type="Int32" precision="10" not-null="true" />
    <property name="FName" type="String" length="50" not-null="true" />
    <property name="FActive" type="Boolean" not-null="true" />

    <many-to-one name="TSCEnterprise" class="TSCEnterprise" column="fEnterpriseID" not-null="true" />
    <set name="TBADepositMasters" table="tBADepositMaster" inverse="true" cascade="all">
      <key column="fSubTypeID" />
      <one-to-many class="TBADepositMaster" />
    </set>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Which property is the problem? the TSCEnterprise property or TBADepositMasters?

Comment: I think the error message it gives you is fairly clear - what exactly do you need help with? If you save an object, you must also save all object it references. Either by manual call to Save(), or by specifying the appropriate cascade rule on the property in the mapping document.

Comment: Specifically, it is the `TSCEnterprise` property that needs a cascade value.  `cascade="save-update"` usually is a good choice for `many-to-one`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using hbm.xml file to maintain relationship between tables.
If you are using "many to one" relationship that means you are relating Parent to child relationship with a table. You should use insert="false" update="false", like so:

```
<many-to-one
      name="TSCEnterprise" class="TSCEnterprise"
      column="fEnterpriseID" not-null="true"
      insert="false" update="false" />
```